# Find enclosed (surface) area from set of lines

Tags: algorithm, line, linear-algebra, area, surface

I am trying to automatically "fill" all of the areas in my code that are completely enclosed by line(segment)s.

What I have is a grid of fixed size (x,y) in 2D space, and a list of lines, defined by their start- and end-points. These lines do not necessarily enclose a space.

[Visual Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JtlIZ.png)
.

What I am looking for is the area's shaded in the different colors of blue here (specifically their bounding points, as I'm trying to create meshes for these areas)

How could I go about algorithmically finding these areas?

Comment: By the way I've already implemented code for finding intersection-points etc, so I'm not looking for any help finding those, just the areas enclosed by lines.

Comment: While you mention lines from the image it looks like you are referring to segments, which makes it a completely different problem. So which ones do you actually mean?

Comment: I do in fact mean line segments. The lines are NOT of infinite length, but only exist from their start- to their endpoints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to find complete circuits of intersecting line segments that define each area (polygon).

Let's assume the line segments are named with letters (A, B, C, ...).

I'd start by building a table that lets you find intersections by line segment.

```
A -> B
A -> C
A -> D
B -> A
C -> A
C -> D
D -> A
```

(In this example, ACD forms a triangular area, and B is just a stray line segment that happens to cross A.)

Pick a line segment, say A, and check its first intersection, which happens to be with line segment B.  Now we start scanning B's intersections.  B connects back to A, which completes a circuit, but there were only two steps, so it's not a valid area.

Since B has no more intersections, we backtrack and look at A's next intersection, which is with C.  C's first intersection is with A, which completes a circuit, but it's only two steps, so it's not a valid area.  But C's next intersection is D, and D's first intersection is A, which completes a three-step circuit, so now we have valid area, specifically a triangle.  The area is defined by the points of intersections we used in our circuit: Pac, Pcd, Pda.

Once you've explored all the possible paths from A, you'd start again with B.  Note that you'll find areas multiple times, so you have to filter out the duplicates.  But you can't skip checking B altogether, because it might be an edge of another area that you haven't already found.

Comment: After trying to implement this, I'm getting close, but not quite there yet.

For testing purposes I'm using the following example:
[link](https://imgur.com/a/Wwd5m9k)

Which is returning 67! found areas. 
Some of these are incorrect, moving across lines which don't exist.

My Code:

[link](https://pastebin.com/tYd5LVSM)

Comment: An example of an incorrect area that was found being:

From (7.0, 0.0, 8.5)  to  (6.5, 0.0, -4.5)  
From (6.5, 0.0, -4.5)  to  (0.5, 0.0, -4.5) 
From (0.5, 0.0, -4.5)  to  (0.5, 0.0, 8.8)  
From (0.5, 0.0, 8.8)  to  (-6.0, 0.0, 9.0) 
From (-6.0, 0.0, 9.0)  to  (-6.0, 0.0, -4.5)

Comment: After getting a tip from a friend (to turn this around and look at intersections instead of lines), I was able to use Johnson's simple cycle algorithm for undirected graphs to find all of the cycles. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

There is something called the [Shoelace Theorem.](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php?title=Shoelace_Theorem) If I understand you want the area in the shaded [region.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shoelace_formula) It determines the area of a simple [polygon.](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/578047-area-of-polygon-using-shoelace-formula/) Once you find the intersections giving you the points you can find the enclosed area. Alternatively, there are these [convex hull algorithms.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull_algorithms) This is even more [efficient.](https://www.westhoffswelt.de/blog/2009/10/21/calculate-a-convex-hull-the-quickhull-algorithm)

```
    # Area of Polygon using Shoelace formula
# http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shoelace_formula
# FB - 20120218
# corners must be ordered in clockwise or counter-clockwise direction
def PolygonArea(corners):
    n = len(corners) # of corners
    area = 0.0
    for i in range(n):
        j = (i + 1) % n
        area += corners[i][0] * corners[j][1]
        area -= corners[j][0] * corners[i][1]
    area = abs(area) / 2.0
    return area

# examples
corners = [(2.0, 1.0), (4.0, 5.0), (7.0, 8.0)]
print PolygonArea(corners)
corners = [(3.0, 4.0), (5.0, 11.0), (12.0, 8.0), (9.0, 5.0), (5.0, 6.0)]
print PolygonArea(corners)


let N           = number of points
let points[N+1] = the array of points
swap points[1] with the point with the lowest y-coordinate
sort points by polar angle with points[1]

# We want points[0] to be a sentinel point that will stop the loop.
let points[0] = points[N]

# M will denote the number of points on the convex hull.
let M = 1
for i = 2 to N:
    # Find next valid point on convex hull.
    while ccw(points[M-1], points[M], points[i]) <= 0:
        if M > 1:
            M -= 1
            continue
        # All points are collinear
        else if i == N:
            break
        else
            i += 1

    # Update M and swap points[i] to the correct place.
    # This code is wrong as explained in the talk page. When M and i are the same, the algorithm ends up in an infinite loop.
    M += 1
    swap points[M] with points[i]
```